# : operator in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

can anyone tell me, what is happening in this code. I tried to search a lot of places but couldn't understand what exactly is the commented part of the code doing.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct XYZ {
    //int a:6; this one.
    char s; 
}structure;

int main() {
     printf("%lu",sizeof(structure)); 
     return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output as 4.

Comment: That's a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

Comment: Lookup bitfields : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Answer (score 4):

That line is commented out. It doesn't do anything.

If it wasn't commented out, it would mean that the size of `int a` is limited to 6 bits only. It's useful for bit-fields inside of a structure.

Comment: 6 bits used and 2 bits reserved for another thing in the same byte ?

Comment: Which 6 bit? First or last in that structure?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik You can check that yourself. Create struct with `int a:1;`, set `a` to 1 and look at the layout. I guess it depends if you're using big or little endian too.